# Do we use quotation marks with like?

Tags: informal-language

For example:

> My little brother went to my mom
>
> He's like mom can you give me 5 dollars?
>
> My mom's like honey I gave you $10 last weekend.

Do I need to use quotation marks after he's like/she's like?

I never do because as far as I know
we always use direct speech in this construction.

I maybe wrong.

Just asking to ensure.

I found this another example:

LYRICS FROM WE'RE NEVER GETTING BACK TOGETHER BY TAYLOR SWIFT:

> Huh, so he calls me up and he's like, I still love you
>   And I'm like I just I mean this is exhausting, you know, like
>   We are never getting back together like, ever

(I don't see any quotation marks here as well)

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to use the super casual, slangy expression "like" ("He's like" or "My mom's like", instead of "He said" or "Then my mom told him"... etc.), it's not really relevant what the "rules" of grammar say about the rest of the sentence, and you can do whatever you please.

However,

> He's like mom can you give me 5 dollars?
>
> My mom's like honey I gave you $10 last weekend.

is a little bit confusing to read because you have to sort out the different meanings of "like" in your head as you read.

It would definitely make the sentences easier to understand if you put quotation marks around the dialog:

> He's like, "Mom can you give me 5 dollars?"
>
> My mom's like, "Honey, I gave you $10 last weekend."

(By the way, you are correct that this is "direct speech", and direct speech normally *does* require quotation marks. The opposite of "direct speech" is "reported speech", which *doesn't* require quotation marks. Example: My mom **told** him **that** she had given him $10 the previous week. [no quote marks])

Answer (score 1):

When people use "like" in the way you mean, my understanding is that what follows *is* a quotation. It is, in effect, used in place of "he said" or "she said". Really then, I would say that the quoted words *should* be in quotation marks.

That said, I don't believe there is a hard and fast rule for this. Putting informal speech into written form is really down to your artistic licence, and in creative writing you can do pretty much what you want to convey informal speech. For example, some writers choose to spell words as they might be pronounced by the speaker (for example "*e's the guv'nor*" to denote a stereotypical Cockney Londoner saying "he's the governor"). Nobody complains that these words are not in the dictionary and it is accepted that you are being creative with the language.

So, if your intention is to convey a certain informal *style* of speech, and maybe imply that what follows "like" isn't a *direct quote* but more the *gist* of what was said then you *could* highlight the text another way, perhaps in *italics*? eg:

> He was like *mom can I have 5 dollars* and she was all like *no you already had ten dollars* and so I was like *nyaaaaaar*....

I would see this as an example of a narrator speaking in the first person and relating a story in which they quote/misquote other people. As narrative does not require quotation marks then there is an argument that none of it should have them as the narrator is saying everything.

There may be some existing examples of writers doing this that you could look at but I doubt there is a "rule".

Answer (score 0):

In *theory* you could write as you have with with *like* and not use quotation marks. However, in the sentences in the question, most people would probably think it was a poor example of English, and a copyeditor would likely replace each instance of *like* with *says* or *said* (in addition to quotation marks).

*Like*, in this sense, is mainly reserved for colloquial English *in speech*, not in writing.

For instance, the sequence in the question could be easily written like this:

> "My little brother went to my mom," I told the audience in front of me. "He's like, mom, can you give me five dollars? And my mom, she's like, honey I gave you ten dollars last weekend."

That use is perfectly fine, because it's clear that it's somebody speaking the words that include *like*.

*Like* is not a formal verb in the sense of to speak, and would very often not be used by anybody in formal writing (or possibly even some informal writing) in the context in the question. It has the same kind of status as using *goes* for speech—something else equivalent to *like*, which would also not normally be used in formal narrative as a replacement for *says*.